# Unable to show the main intent in android emulator using react native

Tags: react-native

Setup the react-native app by react-native init command and running the react-native run-android command to execute the HelloWorld message 
but it's throwing the below error

React native android emulator:

[image: React native android emulator]

Answer (score 0):

Delete your node_modules and reinstall with npm install. Then start up again using `react-native run-android`

Comment: Performed this method before posting question, not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you was calling command in directory of your project? This is really important thing

Comment: Yes im calling inside the project directory